# nodejs how to pass instance?

Tags: node.js

Example:

```
var sessions = require('sessions');
function load_session(req) {
     sessions.load(sid);
}
```

Now that the session is loaded for a session id, how do I pass this session to another module in terms of best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually see sessions just being handled like a singleton. You just use the fully qualified name of the session object and use it directly.

If you're writing tests which need to mock the session, you could always provide a different load_session method which creates a mock version of the session object instead.